# IOS App Deploy Issue: UIImage resolution changed when install through Xcode debug run vs. TestFlight install

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, testflight

I'm very new to iOS App development, I have submitted my App into App Store and able to download into my iPhone, but I found all the UIImages that showing low resolution comparing to installing directly from Xcode build run (assume this is called debug build), I didn't recognize this problem before since all my Xcode build run UIImages all looking good. The devide is the same, so I'm expecting something different between Xcode Debug Build and Production Archive Build.

Following are 2 snapshot from my same devide Iphone 12 Pro Max, first is the Xcode debug run installed App screen (High Resolution), the second snapshot is the app installed through TestFlight and App Store (Low Resolution):

[High Resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/un3AF.jpg)
[Low Resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0mj3.jpg)

All my UIImages comes from "Assets" with following same settings in snapshot

[image: Image Set]

And I searched the "Build Settings" with assets keyword try to figure out if any discrepency between the Debug and Production build, but couldn't find anything suspecious, here is the snapshot of my assets setting in Build Settings:

[image: Build Settings]

I have try to change image format from JPG to PDF but same issue still present, the resolution of the UIImages are different when installing through Xcode debug build run and TestFlight/App Store install.

Has anyone face similar issue before and how do you resolve it, or any advice or experiment that I can try to rootcause this resolution differences?

Thanks in advance!